# Some quantities associated to finite dimensional Hopf algebras

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

let $(H,\Delta,m,s)$ be  a  Hopf algebra. To this Hopf algebra one can associate two obvious linear maps $T_H, S_H:  H \to H $  with $T_H=m\circ \Delta,\quad S_H=s$.

Are there two finite dimensional Hopf algebras $H,H'$ which are not isomorphic Hopf algebras but they are equivalents  in the following sense:

Each coefficient of  characteristic polynomial $Det (T_H-\lambda I)$ equals to the  corresponding coefficient of $Det (T_{H'}-\lambda I)$. Similarly, Each coefficients of $Det (S_H-\lambda I)$ equals to the corresponding coefficients in $Det (S_{H'}-\lambda I)$.That is:$Det(T_H)=Det(T_{H'}),\ldots,trace(T_H)=traceT_{H'}$ and likewise for $S_H$ and $S_{H'}$.

> In the other words, to what extent the set of these coefficients  can determine the nature of  Hopf algebras. Are there some infinite dimensional analogy for these quantities?

Are there two finite groups $G,G'$ of the same orders which are not isomorphic groups but their corresponding Hopf algebras $CG, CG'$ have the  same quantities described above?

Comment: Ali Taghavi, just out of curiosity: what was the motivation? I mean what kind of problem were you studying while these quantities came out ?

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou  To be honest no problem I was working which lead me to this question.  I asked  myself this question Spontaneously(suddenly) without any pre-motivation.   then  I presented at MO.

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou  But may be the  following concept was in my subconscious mind; Hyperrigidity of groups. groups  whose group structre is determined by  $c^*$ algebraic structure  of $c^*_{red} G$.

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou  but i really was considering the alternative coalgebra structure not the group like one.

Answer (score 5):

For a finite group algebra, $T_H(g)=g^2$ and $S_H(g)=g^{-1}$ for any group element $g$.

So for any two finite groups of exponent three and the same order, the quantities will be the same. For example, there's a non-abelian group of order 27 and exponent 3, and also an abelian one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. to be honest   I was considering another comultiplcation with $\Delta f(x,y)=f(xy)$ but you are considering the group like structure.